# Correlation and ratio between two signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I have two signals $x$ and $y$ (blue and red one)

[image]

the Pearson coefficient between them is 0.9659

The yellow signal is the ratio:  `x/y*mean(x)`

The two signals are almost perfectly correlated. How can I have that sine curve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: @Jdip yes it is a theoretical question. Is it possible with a correlation really close to one to have the ratio like that?

Comment: Well, it sure seems so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals are identical other than an offset and a small AM variation. This would result in a very high correlation between the two. To add further intuition, consider the relationship between SNR and the normalized correlation coeffient, $\rho$, which is given as:

$$SNR = 10log_{10}\bigg(\frac{\rho^2}{1-\rho^2}\bigg)$$

In this case the "noise" is the sinusoidal AM error between the two waveforms (more accurately derived as a difference once the mean is removed and both waveforms are scaled by their respective standard deviations). The correlation coefficient of 0.9569 would be an SNR of 10.36 dB. Is it feasible that the power in the sine wave is 10.36 dB lower than the the power in the waveform? If so, then this completely explains what is given.

Comment: thank you, in your opinion what is the source of this am variation?